# How to listen to Azure Notifications Hub events in browser?

Tags: javascript, azure, browser, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have encountered some issues with Azure Notifications Hub with browser.
I have configured the VAPID Keys for my application.
I installed my browser using the API mentioned in this [Microsoft Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/browser-push#create-registrations-and-installations).

To provide some context, I have already configured the VAPID Keys and installed my browser using the API mentioned here:

And installed my browser using this API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-registration
with this body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">    
    <content type="application/xml">        
        <BrowserRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">  
            <Endpoint>https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/.....</Endpoint>            
            <P256DH>{P256DH-value}</P256DH>            
            <Auth>{Auth-value}</Auth>        
        </BrowserRegistrationDescription>    
    </content>
</entry>
```

Additionally, I attempted to register my browser using JavaScript with the following code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("service-worker.js");
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {                 
    if (permission === 'granted') {                     
        // get service worker                     
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((sw) => {                         
            // subscribe                         
            sw.pushManager.subscribe({                             
                userVisibleOnly: true,                             
                applicationServerKey: "VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY"
            }).then((subscription) => {                             
                let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(subscription));       
                console.log(data);                                              
            });                     
        });                 
    }             
});
```

In the service-worker.js file, I have included the following code to handle push events:

```
self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.data);
    const notification = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(notification.title, {
        body: notification.body,
        icon: "icon.png",
        data: {
            notifURL: notification.url
        }
    }));
});
```

Despite my efforts, I am not receiving any events, and the test sends always fail. I kindly request your assistance in troubleshooting and resolving these issues.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, but with installation instead of a registration. Did you find any solution yet?.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue while attempting to listen to browser notifications weather it's registration or installation. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet. To address this problem, I have already submitted a ticket to Microsoft Support, and I'm currently awaiting their response. I will make sure to keep you updated here as soon as I receive any further information.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Also created a ticket. Lets check who wins this race :-) Best regards

Comment: Hi again, i found a solution for my problem, may it helps you too. Please check if you have set a valid subject in azure either aus url or mailto. For instanct mailto:test@push.com. For me this fixed the issue

Comment: That's worked, thanks @urbiwanus, but what is the subject url for? what I can use for?

Comment: See the spec: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8292#section-2.1 Best regards

Comment: @urbiwanus i'm also stuck here. Here's my test payload from Test Send on , not sure what's wrong
`{
    "title": "This is a test",
    "body": "Hello from Azure",
    "aud": "http://localhost/",
    "exp": 1709235381,
    "sub": "mailto:push@example.com"
}`

Comment: First of all you need to add a VAPID Keys in Browser Settings. then you need to create registration/installation using REST APIs. are you done with that?

Comment: @LamaYourz yes, all have been done. I tried both generating vapid keys using built-in function on Azure Portal itself and using other online website. What i'm not sure is that the link @urbiwanus shared mentioned about `aud` and `sub` in the VAPID jwt claims but both Azure & other online VAPID generator sites don't provide input for that